# How to get the index column in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame **A** with the first column as the index vector

> A<-

```
       lon      lat    
6125 84.89329 28.13659  
6126 84.91402 28.18123  
6127 84.93443 28.22521  
6171 84.93212 28.12301  
6172 84.95287 28.16764  
6219 84.99166 28.15405  
6220 85.01210 28.19802
```

How to extract the index vector **x**=(6125,6126,6127,6171,6172,6219,6220)' in R ?

Comment: Maybe `rownames(A)` or `attr(A, "row.names")` ?

Comment: @Richard Scriven Thanks a lot. It is giving the desired result.